# How can I bind to an element within a list, within a observable collection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the following problem:

I have an ObservableCollection as my model, which looks like this:

```
public class HistoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>>> _valuePairs;
    public ObservableCollection<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>>> ValuePairs
    {
        get
        {
            return this._valuePairs;
        }
        set
        {
            this._valuePairs= (ObservableCollection<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>>>)value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ValuePairs");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this collection consists of lists, i need to bind to the KeyValuePair in the list. But i don't know how. The problem is I cannot know how many items will be in the collection nor in the list.

my attempt right now looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValuePairs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <charting:Chart Width="400" Height="250">
                <charting:Chart.Series>
                    <charting:LineSeries Title="Monthly Count" 
                                            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding //, Path=Key}"
                                            DependentValueBinding="{Binding //, Path=Value}">
                    </charting:LineSeries>
                </charting:Chart.Series>
            </charting:Chart>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It displays how much elements are in the collection, but the chart does not show any values.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that Binding / only works, if you use the SynchronizedWithCurrentItem property. I don't know this Chart control, but if it is an ItemsControl there should be support for that.

Comment: Well .. I don't know if it has or not, it a chart from the WPFToolkit library.

Answer (score 0):

Add ItemsSource="{Binding}" to the chart and it should fix it